# How common usage are Page Methods in ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net

How common usage are Page Methods in ASP.NET 4?

I would like an example of how it's used (not a code sample).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by Page Methods in ASP.NET 4, do you meant just a Function or Routine on the page itself for doing a certain job or getting some data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about how common, but check out this example: http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.all

Use page methods if you don't want to publicly expose a web service, and creating a web method that's specifically only to that page, IMHO.  So for instance, I need web service features for one page only, that's when I create a page method.  If I need something reusable in two pages, but don't want to publically expose it, I create a helper and the web method wraps the helper.

Otherwise, if you are looking to create a dynamic web site and share information, go with a traditional ASMX or WCF service.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

In your ASPX file you'll need this line.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

In your code behind define a method marked as a WebMethod.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod()
{
   //code.....
```

Then to call that method in JavaScript.

```
PageMethods.SendForm(SuccessCallBack, FailureCallBack);
```

There are more advanced examples out there - just Google it.

Comment: I know how to code it, I wanted an example why to use it in the first place.

Comment: I'd say "example" is the wrong term then. "reason" seems more fitting (but this isn't http://english.stackexchange.com/ :p).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about usage, but [this is a very basic and clear example](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx).